# setting points on seekbar - ANDROID

Tags: android, position, android-seekbar

I want to be able to set points or steps on the seekbar. I have about 4-5 values that will change according to the position of the seek bar. The way I doing this now is by saying if seekbar position is below 25 then first value, if seekbar position is below 50 second value etc. It would be better if I can just have 4 position on the seekbar instead of 1->100. I have provided a picture below if what I mean.

[image]

**Code:**
Slider is the seekbar, slidertext is a textview

```
slider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
                new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                    int sliderValue;
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                        sliderValue= progress;
                        sliderText.setText("Slider Position: " + sliderValue  + "/" + slider.getMax());
                        if(sliderValue <= 25){
                            playerInput.setText("Player1");
                        }
                        else if(sliderValue <= 50){
                            playerInput.setText("Player2");
                        }
                        else if(sliderValue <= 75){
                            playerInput.setText("Player3");
                        }
                        else if(sliderValue <= slider.getMax()){
                            playerInput.setText("Player4");
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the number of positions to 4 by calling

```
    slider.setMax(4);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your .xml file of the seekbar component you can place the points you want with "max" and with "tickMark" you can add the icon which you want customizing

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
                    android:max="3"
                    app:tickMark="@drawable/dot_inactive"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes thank you for your suggestion